# When can you replace "of" with "from"?

Tags: prepositions

I am having trouble with the following:

> Magic extract of the Nucleoid Membranes of Quasimop Eggs of ancient
>   Dinosaurs.

The way I have learned english, *`of`* is correct in all cases above. If you can say *`The dinosaur's eggs`* and *`The membrane's extract`* the word of choice is *`of`* and not *`from`*. *`Eggs of Dinosaurs`*.

However I feel there are too many "of"-s in the Quote above. Eggs do come from Dinosaurs and the extract does come from Nucleoid Membranes, therefore would it be legal to rephrase it into:

> Magic extract from the Nucleoid Membranes of Quasimop Eggs from
>   ancient Dinosaurs.

?

It would sound and look a lot nicer.

Comment: *Eggs of*, not *eggs from*, definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Extract **from***, not *extract of*;  *eggs **of***, not *eggs from*.

> Magic **extract from** the Nucleoid **Membranes of** Quasimop **Eggs of** ancient Dinosaurs.

But why not:

> Magic **extract from** the Nucleoid **Membranes of** ancient Dinosaurs' Quasimop **Eggs**.

?